# Как вывести записи из mongodb с помощью mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Есть БД 'CLIENTS', но какие внутри коллекции, я не знаю. Как мне вывести с помощью mongoose найти названия этих коллекция и вывести записи из них?

Comment: Может вам не нужен mongoose, а нужно просто посмотреть что внутри базы?

Comment: ну как , получилось?

Comment: использовал mongodb.MongoClient